# How to call lit component in react with ScopedElementsMixin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lit-element, lit

I want to use web component Button (lit) in my project with similar tag. For example: **if tag `<button-test>` exists on website then create tag `<button-test-12345>`**. That's why I use ScopedElementsMixin.

Is it possible to call the button-test tag so that the Element converts it to a tag with the number is the button-test exists on the page?

Lit element

```
import { Button } from '../button/Button';
export class MyElement extends ScopedElementsMixin(LitElement) {
   constructor() {
       super();
       this.defineScopedElement('button-test', Button);
   }

   render() {
       return html`
           <slot></slot>
       `;
   }
}
```

React call

```
if (!customElements.get("my-element")) {
    customElements.define("my-element", MyElement);
}
let result: JSX.Element = <my-element">
   <button-test
      disabled={false}
      text={this.getTextElement()}
   </button-test>
</my-element">;
```

Answer (score 0):

Two options come to mind when making an assumption that you want to provide a nice React component name for `button-test` while using an obfuscated or scoped custom element tag name behind the scenes.

#### Wrap the component for React

One option is to wrap the `Button` custom element with a [`React wrapper`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@lit-labs/react), which allows renaming it for usage within React independent of the underlying custom element tag name.

This would allow using a very obfuscated `button-test` custom element name which is unlikely to collide with another registered name while also providing a nice React component name. For example:

```js
// This simulates a jsx file using the `ButtonTest` React component.

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector('#app'));
root.render(<div>
    <p>Custom element with renamed React component name <code>ButtonTest</code>:</p>
    <ButtonTest></ButtonTest>
  </div>);
```

```html
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script type="module">
import {LitElement, html} from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/lit/dist@2/core/lit-core.min.js';
import {createComponent} from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@lit-labs/react@1.1.0/index.min.js';

export class Button extends LitElement {
  render() {
    return html`<button>Test Button</button>`;
  }
}
// Register the button with a hard to collide name.
const obfuscatedName = "button-test-12345";
customElements.define(obfuscatedName, Button);

// Use @lit-labs/react to create a React component with a nice name.
const ButtonTest = createComponent({
  react: React,
  tagName: obfuscatedName,
  elementClass: Button,
});

// Assigning the react wrapped component to Window to use in the jsx file.
// This is only for StackOverflow.
window.ButtonTest = ButtonTest
</script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

#### Instantiate the custom element from the class

Another option is changing how the button is constructed. Once a custom element has been defined, it is possible to instantiate it from the class, e.g. `new Button()`. This could be used to abstract away the custom element tag name and could maybe be used for creating an abstraction for React usage. E.g.

```js
class Button extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" })
    this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = "<button>button test</button>";
  }
}
customElements.define('button-test-12345', Button)

// Attach button without using obfuscated tag name.
// This will throw if the class has not been defined
// as was done on line 8.
document.querySelector('#app').append(new Button())
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```

The scoped `button-test` element could be created from `my-element` with a React ref with something like: `const buttonEl = MyElementRef.shadowRoot.createElement('button-test')`, and then that could be used.